# С чего начинать изучение программирования?

Tags: c, c++

Как начать изучение C/C++? Что для этого нужно?

Comment: Уверен что С? Если за плечами совсем ничего больше нет, то это не самый лучший выбор. Если всё же решился, то "Б. Керниган, Д. Ричи Язык программирования Си"

Comment: С ассемблера конечно же. Это даст понимание принципов работы железа и оси.

Comment: А может BASIC ?  Потом ассемблер, C, Lisp, Java, SQL ...

Comment: Ассемблер не может быть потом. Он может быть после.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из книг посоветую Дейтелов: "Как программировать на Си", "Как программировать на Си++".
Но в первую очередь нужен какой-нибудь компилятор и средство для редактирования исходного кода, а еще лучше полноценная [IDE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8).
Под Windows хорошая эта [Ms Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/). По ссылке выберете С++, язык лучше английский.
Удачи =)

Answer (score 1):

Мой вам совет это:

1. найти хорошие видео лекции по ООП;
2. купить книгу Герберт.Ш. "C++ для начинающих", желательно в печатном варианте;
3. составить план занятий;
4. найти хорошую книгу по программированию, которую будете читать на досуге.

PS  Тут главное упорство и желание.
PS2 Найти хороший задачник.
PS3 Я бы посоветовал для начинающего небольшой компилятор devc++.

Answer (score 1):

Книги Михаила Фленова %language_name% глазами хакера. Он приводит примеры того как НЕ надо прогаммировать. Сам начинал с "С++ глазами хакера".

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с

> купить книгу Герберт.Ш. "C++ для начинающих", желательно в печатном варианте;

Но такую книгу уже навряд ли найдёте, она чуть по-другому называется "C++ для начинающих. Шаг за шагом" 2010 г. + как обязательный вариант возьмите Стефен Р. Дэвис "С++ для чайников" (звучит некрасиво, зато там объясняют как 5-ти классникам... понятней не найдёте).

Видеоварианты не советовал бы, т.к. программист должен уметь объяснять на пальцах, что он делает... а с видеовариантами получится всё на автомате... Но думаю, что человек собрался не лохокоды писать, а нормальные и всем понятные красивые коды))) так что для начала вышеупомянутые книги советую;-)

Comment: Да! И желательно бы какой-нибудь задачник.... Потому что научиться программировать можно, только программируя))

Answer (score 1):

Лично я начинал с языка паскаль. Не то что бы так и надо, просто изучая паскаль, я постепенно вникал в азы программирования (но для этого не обязательно начинать именно с паскаля). А когда разобрался с азами (операторы, переменные, циклы), я купил себе книжку по с/с++.

На мой взгляд, научиться писать хорошо и качественно невозможно на стадии обучения и самообучения, надо принимать участие в реальных проектах :)

И еще: читайте книги не только про языки программирования. Ищите книги о том, КАК правильно писать программы. Знание языка важно, знание как им правильно пользоваться - еще важнее! Сам я параллельно читаю Стива Макконела "Совершенный код", эдакая библия программиста.

Успехов :)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала купить книгу :) Какую конкретно, думаю люди подскажут или поищите отзывы.
Когда начнете немного ориентироваться, ставьте себе задачи и решайте их.

Comment: 1. Вариант скачать из интернета (легально) - чем-то хуже.

2. Рекомендую эссе Норвига "Изучение программирования за 10 лет" (или похожее) www.norvig.com, есть ссылка на перевод