# С чего начать изучение языка программирования? Например C++.

Tags: c++

Глупый, но нужный вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Изучение основ программирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5261/)
- [Как самостоятельно заниматься по программированию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5564/)
- [Как лучше практиковаться по программированию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6145/)
- [Что нужно чтобы начать программировать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12570/)
- [С чего начать изучение программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5183/)
- [С чего начинать изучение программирования?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/5051/)
- [Руководство пользователя по компилятору C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6031/)

Answer (score 1):

С вывода. Для C++ это поток std::cout и его использование. Напишите hello-world приложение. Далее - переменные и ввод данных пользователя (std::cin в C++). Далее - по списку:

- простая арифметика/математические функции, доступные в языке.
- операторы условного выполнения/ветвления (if/если)
- операторы циклического выполнения (for/для каждого, while/пока)
- ...

Comment: Спасибо. А какое пособие можно использовать для изучения?